# Combobox with calculated value(MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

can somebody help my?
First, I write simple example for you can best understand me.

Let's say, I have VM's Like this:

My DataContext:

```
public class MainWindowVM
{
    private List<DocRow> _rows;

    public List<DocRow> DocumentRows
    {
        get
        {
            return _rows ?? (_rows = new List<DocRow>()
            {
                new DocRow(new Employee(1,"Employee1"),200,4,2),
                new DocRow(new Employee(2,"Employee2"),400,8,0)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My VM for Rows:

```
public class DocRow
{
    public DocRow(Employee employee, double salary, double aBonus, double bBonus)
    {
        Employee = employee;
        Salary = salary;
        ABonus = aBonus;
        BBonus = bBonus;
    }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
    public double ABonus { get; set; }
    public double BBonus { get; set; }
}
```

and my View:

```
<Window x:Class="TestComboboxUserControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestComboboxUserControl"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid 
        ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentRows}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Employee">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Employee,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Salary">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Salary,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="A-Bonus">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding ABonus,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="B-Bonus">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding BBonus,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I will repeat, this is just an example.

What problem i have:
in bussines logic of my company, ABonus can have only one of two Values: 2%*Salary or 0%*Salary
B-Bonus, in his turn can have only two Values to, 0.5%*Salary or 0%*Salary.

What i want:
I want create a usercontrol, what i can use like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="B-Bonus">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <cbb:ComboBoxCalculated SelectedItem="{Binding BBonus,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ComboboxCalculated.PredefinedPercent>
                <CbbItem Value = "0%"/>
                <CbbItem Value = "2%"/>
            </ComboboxCalculated.PredefinedPercent>
        </cbb:ComboBoxCalculated>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

And that it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld4dT.png)

and my vm, of course, must raise OnPropertyChanged A-Bonus And B-Bonus items for recalculated.

And in model must be insert "selectedItem" of combobox? what must be a value 200 as example.
and when load from database selected item must be changed to.
sorry for my bad English, I hope you can understand me xD

P.S. in this comboboxes, always can be only TWO items, 0% and "x"%
if you can say me a best and userfriendly way to do this function, please talk me.
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure that i understand what you you looking for, but i think you should change the entries during the input. means when you change the value in the 'Salary' you should update the items in the list 'A-Bonus' and 'B-Bonus' within the viewmodel.

maybe here a little example of my application. it's a price with netto and brutto values, but i really hold just the netto value.

-when the netto value is changed then i trigger just brutto property changed event
-when the brutto value is changed, i change the netto DATA MODEL value and trigger just the netto property changed event.

```
/// <summary>price purchase netto</summary>
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Validation.RequiredIf("Class", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CarPlus.Base.Properties.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "General_Required")]
    [Range(0, 10000000, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CarPlus.Base.Properties.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ViewModelVehicle__PriceRange")]
    public decimal? PricePurchaseNetto
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.__dataModel.PricePurchaseNetto);
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.__dataModel.PricePurchaseNetto != value)
            {
                this.__dataModel.PricePurchaseNetto = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("PricePurchaseNetto");
                Log.Logger.DebugFormat("{0}:{1} - set('{2}')", this.FullName, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, value == null ? "NULL" : value.ToString());


                this.RaisePropertyChanged("PricePurchaseBrutto");
            }
        }
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>price purchase brutto</summary>
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Validation.RequiredIf("Class", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CarPlus.Base.Properties.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "General_Required")]
    [Range(0, 10000000, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(CarPlus.Base.Properties.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ViewModelVehicle__PriceRange")]
    public decimal? PricePurchaseBrutto
    {
        get
        {
            return (Helpers.GetBrutto(this.__dataModel.PricePurchaseNetto, this.VatVerifiable && !this.VatImportWithout ? this.VatPurchase : null));
        }
        set
        {
            this.__dataModel.PricePurchaseNetto = Helpers.GetNetto(value, this.VatVerifiable && !this.VatImportWithout ? this.VatPurchase : null);
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("PricePurchaseNetto");
            Log.Logger.DebugFormat("{0}:{1} - set('{2}')", this.FullName, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, value == null ? "NULL" : value.ToString());
        }
    }
```